# if the browser window is below a certain height addClass to an element

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to `addClass` to an element if the browser window is below a certain size via `height`; when and only if the height is below a certain point.

Using jQuery how could I detect current browser height and below for this to occur?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Use _media queries_ instead of JS

Comment: If you guys hate the question - why provide answers, so I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).height() < 500) {
        $('.element').addClass('className');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While JavaScript is a possible option for this, it's quite an inefficient one at many times. If you are able to use CSS, you can use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Here's an example:

```css
html > body {
  background: blue;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  body {
    background: red !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body></body>

</html>
```

If you run that, when the page is less than 500px high, the background will be red. Otherwise, it will be blue.

Comment: DOn't use W3fools for reference, use MDN

Comment: @Tushar I was going to, but I didn't want to confuse him further with the better website!

Comment: DON'T, that'll not _confuse_ it'll be far better than w3schools, please update the link

Comment: @Tushar I saw your edit and thought you already had, it's updated now.